# How to export report in php codeigniter where database rows are displayed as column name in excel sheet

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

I am trying to generate a weekly report where i want to display count of people for individual day in a week.For example i want last week report where date is 17/02/2020 to 21/02/2020.

```
Unit Name    |17/02/2020   |18/02/2020  |19/02/2020  |20/02/2020  |21/02/2020
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
unit_1       |  21         |  56        | 78         | 09         | 05
unit_2       |  10         |  18        | 23         | 12         | 112
unit_3       |  15         |  65        | 06         | 00         | 74
unit_4       |  53         |  36        | 11         | 02         | 23
unit_5       |  75         |  25        | 22         | 23         | 00
unit_6       |  78         |  24        | 00         | 05         | 18
```

How can i get report in above format.

I have used $this->dbutil->csv_from_result for exporting report as excel sheet.Here i have People_table where data is entered on daily basis.In report i need to disply count of P_id for individual day of week.table structure is as below:

```
auto_id |unit_id |   date      |P_id
-----------------------------------
1       |  1     | 17/02/2020  | 100     
2       |  1     | 17/02/2020  | 101    
3       |  1     | 17/02/2020  | 102 
4       |  3     | 18/02/2020  | 103    
5       |  6     | 18/02/2020  | 104    
6       |  4     | 18/02/2020  | 105
7       |  5     | 19/02/2020  | 106     
8       |  5     | 19/02/2020  | 107    
9       |  2     | 19/02/2020  | 108 
10      |  2     | 19/02/2020  | 109    
11      |  6     | 19/02/2020  | 110     
12      |  4     | 19/02/2020  | 111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT unit_id,date
FROM table) AS ptable
PIVOT(
CONCAT(unit,'_',unit_id) FOR unit_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(unit_id) FROM table),
date FOR date IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(date) FROM table)
)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.